# Error en ejecucion de Script con modificaciones en mySQL

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo las Siguientes funciones en JavaScript:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function HabilitarConfirm() {
  var mensajeH = confirm("¿Desea Habilitar al Estudiante?");
  if (mensajeH) {
    <?php             
    require '../../database.php';
    $resulta = $conn->query("UPDATE infoEstudiante
                            SET estadoEstudiante='1'
                            WHERE idEstudiante=$ID;");
    ?>
    alert("¡El Estudiante fue Habilitado!");
    window.close();
  }
}

function DeshabilitarConfirm() {
  var mensajeD = confirm("¿Desea Inhabilitar al Estudiante?");
  if (mensajeD) {
    <?php
    require '../../database.php';
    $resulta = $conn->query("UPDATE infoEstudiante
                            SET estadoEstudiante='0'
                            WHERE idEstudiante=$ID;");
    ?>
    alert("¡El Estudiante fue Inhabilitado!");
    window.close();
  }
}
```

pero al intentar llamarlo desde esta sentencia de html/php

```html
<?php require '../../database.php';
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM infoEstudiante WHERE idEstudiante = $ID;");
  $numfilas = $result->num_rows;
  $aux = $result->fetch_object();
  mysqli_close($conn);

$estado=$aux->estadoEstudiante;

  if ($estado == 1) {
    ?><input type="button" name="disable" value="Deshabilitar Estudiante" onclick="DeshabilitarConfirm()"><?php
  } elseif ($estado == 0) {
    ?><input type="button" name="able" value="Habilitar Estudiante" onclick="HabilitarConfirm()"><?php
  }
?>
```

me genera error y solo me deja usar el de mas abajo :/, al intercambiarlos siempre termina funcionando el de mas abajo...

¿Cuál será el Problema?

Comment: Testea y dime lo que te está entregando ese $aux->estadoEstudiante, es más, necesito ver dónde y cómo creas esa variable $aux

Comment: Sale de hacer el fetch a la tupla de mySQL, ahí ingreso el codigo editado.

Comment: No es necesario que las inserciones las hagas de esa forma, ya que PHP se ejecuta de manera inmediata y no respeta las sentencia de javascript, osea que cada que recargues la pagina se haran 2 actualizaciones a la tabla de tu base de datos. Para eso puedes usar ajax...

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error en específico y cuáles son los resultados de tu debuggeo? Por favor enfoca también tu título para que personas con el mismo problema puedan encontrar una solución más rápido.

Comment: Lo intentaré entonces por ajax. Gracias.

Comment: Fernando, el Script esta asociado a un botón, al presionarlo no genera ninguna acción. Pero al Intertarlo con la funcion de abajo si ejecuta el Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar ajax y tu código funcione solamente cuando se interactúa o se presione un botón en este caso, los botones **Habilitar** y **Deshabilitar**.

Solo necesitas crear un archivo llamado `update.php`, con este código:

```php
<?php
  require '../../database.php';
  $ID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); // de esta forma evitamos que se inyecte código a tu base de datos.
  $state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'state', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
  if (isset($_POST['state']) && isset($_POST['id'])) {
    // no remuevas los '?'
    $resulta = $conn->prepare("UPDATE infoEstudiante
                            SET estadoEstudiante=?
                            WHERE idEstudiante=?");
    $resulta->execute([$state, $ID]);
  }
?>
```

Para hacer inserciones vía ajax, vas a necesitar axios un pequeña librería que facilita el uso de ajax

*Consejo: tu código javascript siempre mantelo abajo de todo tu html y antes del cierre de la etiqueta 'body'*

Crea un archivo llamado 'main.js' con el siguiente código;

```
function HabilitarConfirm() {
  var mensajeH = confirm("¿Desea Habilitar al Estudiante?");
  if (mensajeH) {
    axios.post('/update.php', {
      id: <?php echo $ID; ?>,
      state: 1
    })
    .then(function () {
      alert("¡El Estudiante fue Habilitado!");
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
}

function DeshabilitarConfirm() {
  var mensajeD = confirm("¿Desea Inhabilitar al Estudiante?");
  if (mensajeD) {
    axios.post('/update.php', {
      id: <?php echo $ID; ?>,
      state: 0
    })
    .then(function () {
      alert("¡El Estudiante fue inhabilitado!");
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
}
```

Y antes del cierre de la etiqueta body, agregas este código

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>
```